# Data cannot be written into another file after modifying it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to get the content of a file, modify it and write it in another file. But nothing is written in the destination file! thesize of the file is 0.

Here is my code:

```
keyword_array = []
#NumberPhrases = []
#keyword_array2 = []    
f = open('Drive\\API_Extract_Phrases.txt', 'wb')
with open('Drive\\extract_keywords\\test.txt') as my_keywordfile:        
    for line in my_keywordfile.readlines():
        for keyword in line.strip("[]").strip("'").split(","):  

          keyword_array.append(keyword.strip().strip("'").lower().encode())                 

    f.writelines(keyword_array);
    f.flush();
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks,

Comment: What does `print(keyword_array)` tell you?  Try replacing `f.flush()` with `f.close()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the file. Use `f.close()` after you are done modifying the file.